# Winforms - An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

I'm trying to make an "updater" for my program and one of the things I need to do is download the exe from a url. I'm trying to use `WebClient.DownloadFile` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm getting an error: `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'WebClient.DownloadFile(string, string)'`. I'm assuming this is something stupid I've overlooked, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
private void Update()
{
    string downloadURL = EXE_LOCATION;
    string progName = Application.ExecutablePath.Substring(Application.ExecutablePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    string progLoc = Application.ExecutablePath.Substring(0, Application.ExecutablePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

    if (File.Exists(progLoc + progName))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Move(progLoc + progName, progLoc + "Old-version.exe");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem renaming: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    WebClient.DownloadFile(downloadURL, progLoc + progName);
}
```

Comment: `DownloadFile` is not static. You need an instance of `WebClient`.

Comment: WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    webclient.DownloadFile(downloadURL, progLoc + progName);  I really need to figure out how to put code correctly in comments, lol.

Comment: There are methods in .Net which will split the path and file for you - `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` to get the location, and `Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath)` for the name.

Comment: @jpaugh78 use backticks - ` code ` becomes `code` (without the spaces)

Comment: Are you trying to update your application from within the application, as suggested by using [`Application.ExecutablePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath(v=vs.110).aspx)? If so, you certainly won't need to check if the file exists, but also certainly it won't work as the file will be in use..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(downloadURL, progLoc + progName);
}
```

`WebClient` is just the name of the class. You need a reference to an instance of the class. Understanding the difference between types, instances, references and variables is critical; unless this is well-understood you will struggle to be an effective programmer.

While I'm here: get rid of the `File.Exists()` check. You're already catching an exception. Let that handle the problem if the file doesn't exist.